# Use waitOn on separate blocks in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

I am fairly new to Meteor. I am using `iron-router` to route on the page. I always set the `waitOn` property, making the page load until the publications are subscribed.

But on many pages I see they load panels/cards separately, i.e. the page loads but some elements on the page load concurrently and are sometimes finished loading on different times.

Is such behaviour also possible in Meteor, instead of always waiting for all the subscriptions to load before the page can be shown?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Ways to achieve this behaviour include Template-level subscriptions, Handlebars checks, lazy-loaded cursors, method calls on render event, ...  Good answers would be very long to produce. Please search for these words and come back when you have a more specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a concrete answer to this question, but progressive loading is actually the default in meteor. If you [subscribe in IR](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#the-subscriptions-option), or globally, or from [your template](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe), documents will flow to your client from the server and your templates should render the data as it becomes available. Note that in many cases, you'll need to add some [guards](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) to your code in order to fix certain race conditions.

Using [waitOn](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#the-waiton-option) is a special use of subscriptions where you block rendering of a template until the initial set of documents has arrived on the client. It should be used in cases where the UI doesn't make sense with a progressive load (you need to see all of the data at once).

I hope that helps give a general overview. If you have specific questions, just leave a comment and I'll do my best to add more detail where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it exists I think you're looking for the `Template.subscribe` http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe

waiting for all subscriptions is Iron-Router way, If you want dynamic UI where some parts of the website will just show loadng when the subscriptions is not ready here is the example copied from the docs:

```
<template name="notifications">
  {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    <!-- This is displayed when all data is ready. -->
    {{#each notifications}}
      {{> notification}}
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    Loading...
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

And you need to subscribe inside onCreated callback

```
Template.notifications.onCreated(function () {
  // Use this.subscribe inside onCreated callback
  this.subscribe("notifications");
});
```

`flow-router` is actually better for this kind of behavior it actually built to support this kind of subscriptions management.